# Ubuntu 14.04 unable to locate package install libatlas-base-dev

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

After many attempts and web searching I decided to ask :)

I am trying to install **scipy** on Ubuntu 14.04. As I have it **libatlas-base-dev** is a dependancy.

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

returns **Unable to locate package**

Ubuntu Software Server returns **Not found**. Same with `sudo pip install libatlas-base-dev`.

Please help.

Comment: have you enabled the `universe` repository?

Answer (score 2):

try to do this:

make update to your package in first time and install the package after

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --yes install libatlas-base-dev
```

it works well in ubuntu 16

Answer (score -1):

In order to install SciPy Stack on Ubuntu OS, you have to install the folowing packages :

- python-numpy
- python-scipy
- python-matplotlib
- ipython
- ipython-notebook
- python-pandas
- python-sympy
- python-nose

So, just run this command from a sudoer user :

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

or this one from root account :

```
# apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

Comment: I have the same problem as @HenkG, in that I'm `unable to locate package`, though encounter this problem not through installing Scipy. Your answer doesn't really answer the question directly, I'd rather you answered how to enable Ubuntu to locate the package.

Comment: Which package do you are not able to locate ?